# How to add + into rule

Tags: regex, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm current struggling with adding '+' sign to the rule in a phone field by validation(because some people might write like +61425500234)

```
 'phone' => array(
                'notempty' => array(
                    'rule' => '/^[0-9][+]{10,}$/i',
                    //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                    //'allowEmpty' => false,
                    //'required' => false,
                    //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                    //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
                ),
            ),
```

but I realised that it doesn't work somehow and I tried to search online and there is no example to suit my case. If someone got any ideas pls feel free to post your thoughts.

Comment: Hi, Ive worked it out just by using forward slash line: 'rule' => '/^[0-9\+]{10,}$/i', this will be the solution

Comment: That would also match `123+456+789+0`

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a [meta-character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php), you must escape it in order for it being treated as a simple char.

Also you want to check for it at the beginning of the string.

```
'/^\+?[0-9]{10,}$/i'
```